# Text field doesn't appear in application

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I'm retrieving information from my `SQLite` database and display it in a `RecyclerView` through an `ArrayList`. My code works fine with no errors, however, 1 out of the 4 `TextViews` that I'm trying to show cannot be displayed even though it follows exactly the same methods as the other 3 and I have no idea why.

Activity with RecyclerView:

```
public void search(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, Name, Surname, Department, Workplace FROM LysandrosTable WHERE Name || ' ' || Surname LIKE ?",
            new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    lysandrosHelper = new LysandrosDatabaseAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new EmployeeListAdapter(lysandrosHelper.getAllDat(), R.layout.custom_row2));

}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtFirstName_Recycler;
    public TextView txtLastName_Recycler;
    public TextView txtDepartment_Recycler;
    public TextView txtWorkplace_Recycler;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        txtFirstName_Recycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name_recycler);
        txtLastName_Recycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_name_recycler);
        txtDepartment_Recycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.department_recycler);
        txtWorkplace_Recycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.workplace_recycler);
    }

}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DataBean item = items.get(position);

    holder.txtFirstName_Recycler.setText(item.getName());
    holder.txtLastName_Recycler.setText(item.getSurname());
    holder.txtDepartment_Recycler.setText(item.getDepartment());
    holder.txtWorkplace_Recycler.setText(item.getWorkplace());

}
```

My database class with the corresponding method:

```
public List <DataBean> getAllDat(){

    List<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String [] columns = {LysandrosHelper.UID, LysandrosHelper.NAME, LysandrosHelper.SURNAME, LysandrosHelper.DEPARTMENT, LysandrosHelper.WORKPLACE};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(LysandrosHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(LysandrosHelper.UID);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LysandrosHelper.NAME);
        int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LysandrosHelper.SURNAME);
        int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LysandrosHelper.DEPARTMENT);
        int index5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(LysandrosHelper.WORKPLACE);
        int cid = cursor.getInt(index);

        String persoName = cursor.getString(index2);
        String personSurname = cursor.getString(index3);
        String personDepartment = cursor.getString(index4);
        String personWorkplace = cursor.getString(index5);

        DataBean bean = new DataBean(cid, persoName, personSurname, personDepartment, personWorkplace);
        list.add(bean);
    }

    return list;
}
```

And the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_48dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/first_name_recycler"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last_name_recycler"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_name_recycler"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/first_name_recycler"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/department_recycler"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_name_recycler"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/workplace_recycler"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/department_recycler"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/department_recycler"
            android:layout_below="@+id/last_name_recycler"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `TextView` not displayed is Workplace.

Comment: Which TextView is not displayed? Also, use `tools:text="Some test text"` in your TextView layouts to make sure that layout is not the problem.

Comment: I've mentioned at the end of my post which one. The workplace_recycler one. I've also had text before and still doesn't appear whereas on every other text field it does.

Comment: Would you require more info??

Comment: Are you sure that `String personWorkplace = cursor.getString(index5);` is not an empty string?

Comment: Yea pretty sure..Am I missing something? Because I've been looking into this for at least 3 hours and my brain is a bit disfunctional now:/

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure your layout is badly written, and localized text expansion inside `first_name_recycler` can cause height or width of other TextViews to be 0. Basically, if one of your textViews is too large, there's no space for other. 
Try a simpler layout, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/first_name_recycler"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last_name_recycler"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/department_recycler"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/workplace_recycler"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work and this design is different than the one that I'm trying to achieve